# Windows 8.1 Update 1 locked me out of bios, what to do?

Tags: bios, windows-8.1

I tried to access the system menu to access the bios by pressing the ESC key while my system was starting up, but that did not lead me into bios nor did allow me to choose options such as boot order.

This worked before I upgraded because I use it quite a few times every week.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Every manufacturer uses a different key to get to BIOS settings on boot. (Keys to try <kbd>DEL</kbd> or <kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd>).

But you can also ask Windows 8.x to boot into BIOS:

1. Open `Settings`, then select `General`
2. Under `Advanced Startup`, click on `Restart Now` - this will restart your computer into the boot menu
3. in the boot menu click on `Troubleshoot` - this will open a screen called `Advanced Settings`
4. Select UEFI Firmware Settings, which will open the BIOS

I read somewhere you can achieve the same result by holding <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> while restarting Windows, but I never tried it.

Comment: 1. I don't have UEFI.
2. ESC worked before.

Comment: Interesting. It could be that the system boots too fast for you to get into BIOS. Did you try holding Shift while selecting restart?

Comment: System does NOT boot too fast, it seems. I do see a blinking "_" in the beginning, but I don't see the message "Press Esc for boot menu..." now. I still try to press ESC but that does nothing. I really have no idea why.